# are node modules dependency lazy loaded?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, git-submodules

My question is are the node modules dependencies are lazy loaded in any way?
or it's just the magic of imports?

As I have built a [git submodule](https://github.com/prabhatmishra33/myapp-poc-ui/) and doing `Lazy Loading` using `react-loadable` but it hardly seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Node_Modules are not lazy loaded. Here you are using `react-loadable` which is nothing but a dynamic import in JS/JSX file. Whenever webpack finds the import statement in js file it will create the chunk file and reference will be added to the main js file. In browser network tab you can see the multiple files.

`react-loadable` is useful for large scale project, where it will has multiple pages. That time it is not a good practice to bundle all js into single file. In that case `react-loadable` create multiple chunks and loaded whenever the components needs to be present in the screen.

Comment: yeah `webpack` creates a junk but these junks never gets picked up when i use in the main application. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256536/unhandled-rejection-chunkloaderror-loading-chunk-1-failed